# How to control class visibility by owner in c#

Tags: c#, class, visibility

Often I want some (or all) functions of some class C1 to be accessible only from within another class C2, because C2 is kind of a proxy, it owns objects of type C1 (e.g.: methods of a class "Neuron", like "connect()", should only be accessible from "Brain"). I assume this is not directly possible with C# unlike with inheritance, where we can specify visibility with a keyword like "private" or "protected".

What is the best practice in such a situation?

Answer (score 5):

Create an assembly for your classes and declare the internal class that should not be visible to the outside world as `internal`:

> [internal (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7c5ka91b.aspx):
>
> The `internal` keyword is an access modifier for types and type members. Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly

So, something like this:

```
namespace YourAssembly.Classes
{
    internal class C1
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
        
        }
    }
    
    public class C2
    {
        public void DoFoo()
        {
            new C1().Foo();     
        }
    }
}
```

Here `C2` is accessible from other assemblies, while `C1` can only be accessed from within the same assembly.

Comment: `internal` is visible to the entire DLL, not the namespace.

Answer (score 3):

If `C1` cannot be accessed by anybody but `C2`, then make `C1` a `private` class of `C2`.

```
public class C2
{
    public C2() { }

    private class C1
    {
        public C1() { }
    }
}
```

However, if `C1` can be accessed outside of `C2`, then you're going to need to pass in some kind of `key` into the `ctor` of `C2` to ensure it's a **trusted** proxy.

```
public class C1
{
    public C1(string key)
    {
        // verify that it's a valid proxy or user of this class via the key
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that private class is not an option, because functions of C2 must be accessible to several other classes.

Comment: This solution solves a compile-time problem by adding run-time execution. It's not the right way to do this.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: The problem is a compile-time problem. The aim here is to prevent other coders to access methods that they shouldn't. Your solution implies using logic at run time, ie identifying that a key is correct each time you call a method. This solution impairs the performance of the code...

Answer (score 0):

A trick often used for testing purposes is to use the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx). You apply it to an assembly (exe or dll) like this

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("NameOfFriendAssembly")]
```

Classes (and other types) and members defined as `internal` will then be visible internally of cause but also to the assembly `NameOfFriendAssembly`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best for you is to do something like this:

```
public interface INeuron 
{
   double GetValue();
   List<INeuron> GetDependents();
   List<double> GetWeights();
}

internal class Neuron : INeuron
{
   // implementation of INeuron
   // ...

   // implementation of methods only known to own classes
   public void Connect(Neuron target, double weight)
   {
      ...
   }
}

public class Brain
{
   private List<Neuron> _allNeurons = new List<Neuron>();       

   public Brain()
   {
      Neuron n1 = new Neuron();
      Neuron n2 = new Neuron();
      n1.Connect(n2,0.5);
      _allNeurons.Add(n1);
      _allNeurons.Add(n2);
   }

   public IEnumerable<INeuron> GetAllNeurons() { return _allNeurons.Cast<INeuron>(); }
}
```

Comment: You can still call Connect() from any other class inside the assembly, if you are not cautious. What is really needed is compiler support for this problem IMHO.

Comment: @Yekoor: I disagree. You see, I think you're making a very common mistake, that is to think code visibility in terms of class concepts rather than in term of API access. **A method on `Neuron` is public because external clients of the DLL should be allowed to access it, not because a `Brain` should be able to connect `Neuron`s**. Within your own library, it is your responsibility to not call methods that shouldn't be called. Code visibility should only be used to control projects that depends on your DLL, and that is controlled with the `internal` keyword.

Comment: what you are writing is not compatible with the definition of the problem. I don't have a library, even though I didn't explicitly state it, so I don't think in term of API access. And why should it be my own responsibility, if we can theoretically delegate it to the compiler, just like with inheritance access control?

Comment: What I am saying is that method visibility should not be used to model your problem, but to restrict what's available to DLLs (mostly to restrict dependencies). It has nothing to do with the fact that `Brain` should be able to access `Neuron.Connect()` or not